# Calling different actions from the same controller/view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's the scenario:
I am working on a file/folder management system. when i want to create a new folder i want to create it in the server and also in the dropBox (using an API).
The way my code is organized right now is that i have two controllers, one for the folders "Folder" and one for DropBox interactions "DropBox"

Using the return RedirectToAction() works for me but i dont think it's the best way to do it.

here's the order of my calls:
- From the Folder view  i call create_folder in the "Folder" controller.
- After doing all the processing in the "Folder" controller I  redirect to the "DropBox" controller using return RedirectToAction("create_Folder","DropBox")
- After doing all the processing in the "DropBox" controller i redirect back to the "Folder" index view to display the created folder.

I don't think it's the best way to do it. i think it's a routing concept that i am not really understanding here.
When i tried to add a new action in the folder controller (I called it Create_Folder_complete) and included Create_Folder() and then call Create_Folder_DRopBox() i got a reference null error message.

what am i missing here? i want to make my code as clean as possible and follow the MVC best practices.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have separate actions for each task. The action is responsible for creating the "folder". The fact that it's also interacting with DropDox to create a folder there is an implementation detail that shouldn't be exposed to the enduser. Do *all* the work directly in one action that responds to the submission of your create folder form, and then either redirect to a success page or return the view on error.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, what i am thinking i should do is to add the CreateFolder_DropBox into the Folder controller. i think the controller Folder should manage/process everthing related to folders (server or dropbox)

Comment: Yes, but you need to go further than that. You don't want to redirect the user at all unless it's to something like a success page at the end. Do all the work you need to do in the single POST action for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a service that can handle the processing that you do in the folder controller function AND the dropbox controller function. You can call this service method from your folder controller and then redirect to the index action of the folder controller when it's complete.

Comment: Actually for unit testing purposes you should create 3 services, one that creates a folder, one that handles Dropbox and another that integrates the two.  Your controller should only have to call the third service.  You can then unit test each set of operations in isolation.